# SQL Server 2005 - The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm suddenly having a problem connecting to my local instance of SQL Server 2005 Database engine. I had no problem connecting to this instance a few days ago. I can however connect to Integration Services and Analysis Services. Only the Database engine is giving me this error:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, 
but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. 
(provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - 
The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted) (Microsoft SQL Server)
```

Only thing I did was I installed Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic error that has many reasons. Usually is things like expired password. To troubleshoot, you should enable Netlogon service logging, follow [Enabling debug logging for the Netlogon service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/109626/enabling-debug-logging-for-the-netlogon-service):

```
c:\>Nltest /DBFlag:2080FFFF
```

Then reproduce your problem then look into the logging file, which is going to be located at `%windir%\debug\netlogon.log`. Read the file, try to understand what is happening.

Don't forget to turn off the debug logging afterwards:

```
c:\>Nltest /DBFlag:0
```

Comment: An error occurred when I entered the command. I'm on my home network not on a domain. This is the error: SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters set to 0x2080ffff
I_NetLogonControl failed: Status = 1722 0x6ba RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE